# Starting Node app when AWS server is booting up

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, startupscript

I was wondering if it was possible to call "npm run start" while the machine is booting up by adding it to one of our boot up services. We tried just adding in the command to one of our startup scripts and it fails with some internal error, the only way we can get it to work is by starting a shell within the service and then running those commands within that shell. But we want to get it to start without having to do all that. Is this even feasible? if so, is it good practice to do so and what do we need to look into to get this done. If not, what are some of the approaches we can take to get this type of functionality on our AWS machines.

We have been looking into different things to use like PM2 and such, but just want to make sure we are aware of all the possible ways we can do this and select the best one.

Comment: How did you add it and what was the error?

Comment: If you are planning to use pm2, you can use `pm2 save` after you start your processes and that will make sure they will run after the machines boots.